# GEM5 ARM fs meet panic: VFS:Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) when trying to do a full arm system simulation by gem5

Tags: linux-kernel, gem5

command line:

> build/ARM/gem5.opt --debug-file=dvfs_debug.log ./configs/example/arm/fs_power.py --kernel=./system/binaries/vmlinux4_4_10 --disk ./system/disk/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img --cache --dvfs --big-cpu-clock 3GHz 2GHz 1GHz 900MHz --big-cpu-voltages 1.0V 0.9V 0.8V 0.5V --little-cpu-clock 2GHz 1GHz 800MHz 500MHz --little-cpu-voltages 1.0V 0.8V 0.6V 0.5V

in one kernel, this ends up with "kernel panic: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)"
[pic of kernel panic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeVjJ.png)
in another kernel, this command is stuck at: "
Mount failed for selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux:  No such file or directory"
[pic of failed for selinux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnFj6.png)

I tried two different kernels. I failed for the reasons I mentioned above. I've tried many times in order to enter the simulating system in order to change the cpufreq. So far I haven't succeeded in entering the simulating system.
I have viewed some answers before and changed my root to "dev/vda2" but it seemed not working.
And from this link:[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63277677/gem5-full-system-linux-boot-fails-with-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable)
The clues point to something like:

> CONFIG_VIRTIO_PCI=y
> CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=y
> But I can't find where it is.
> By the way, What's the most popular kernel and disk image in GEM5 DVFS simulation?